# Why my soldering iron tip dissolved?

Tags: soldering

I have used 25 watt tip on 25 watt soldering iron a month ago and within a month there is a huge hole in my needle tip(attaching photos).  It seems like something had dissolved it.  Both of tip and iron is made by soldron.  I am using 60-40 grade soldering wire and wembleys quickfix soldering flux.

[image: tip2]

[image: tip image]

Comment: Is that a plumber's flux?

Comment: Wrong/Active/Acid flux?  Too hot iron?  Wet sponge/rag? Thinly plated (cheap) tip?  All lead to quick tip erosion.  I've been on-site, using the questionable ingredients on-hand, where the tip lasted exactly one soldering session during an emergency repair.  The tip was so hot, that I believe I crossed the boundary from soldering, right through brazing, and directly to welding.  No. Tip. Left.

Comment: It is not dissolved, it is burned.

Comment: @ChrisKnudsen - Hi, Can you make an answer from that comment, even if it's only suggestions? We're getting flags for your comment actually being an answer, so I wanted to give you a chance to keep the contents in an answer, before it gets deleted. Thanks.

Comment: @SamGibson My comment is really just an unsupported answer (and should not qualify as such - I would hope). rdtsc has already done all of the hard work.  I would think that my comment has some utility by providing a description of supporting experience when the tools/methods are not proper.  However, delete away.. if you must.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is a combination of these things:

1. 25W iron with 25W tip was somehow far too hot.  The dark color of the heater area indicates that it was nearly red-hot.  If the unit has a temperature control, turn it down.  If not (no base station/controller), use a lamp dimmer to reduce the effective heat.  If trying to solder something which requires more heat (like a chassis connection), you must use a larger iron than 25W.  I once had to solder a big nut to a piece of steel - got away with a 100W iron by preheating the area with a hot-air gun first.
2. The tips are usually steel-coated which helps with longevity.  If that coating was poor quality, too thin, damaged, or not coated at all, then the base metal (copper) is slowly dissolved into each solder joint.  When that starts happening, replace the tip.  Keep in mind, a cheap soldering iron is going to perform like a cheap soldering iron - there is a reason why professional equipment is expensive.
3. Be aware that 60/40 solder also comes in acid-core variety - such solder must never be used in electronics work as the acid readily eats away everything.  And RohS (lead-free) solder melts at a higher temperature than 60/40 lead-tin solder, so more tip wear is expected when using that.  Consider a lower-temperature solder; google and you should find 63/37 solder that melts at 185°C (as opposed to 250-350°C.)  Just be aware that lower-temp solders tend to not be as strong as the higher-temp stuff.  If you need ultimate strength, use silver solder - but that melts at an even higher temperature.  Always use the right tool for the job.
4. The [QuickFix](http://wembley.in/quickfix.html) soldering paste is the brown stuff in a tin.  Despite it clearly showing a circuit board on the product, this is a zinc chloride-based flux.  I would personally never use that on a circuit board or other fine work.  It is an effective flux, but it tends to be very corrosive at high temperatures.  There are many better fluxes available if working on boards.  When I need extra flux for tough soldering jobs, I use MG Chemicals 835 rosin flux liquid from an eyedropper.  For surface-mount board work, try any of the ChipQuick gel fluxes (smells like cooking beer when hot, interesting.)
5. Technique - On a new tip, coat it immediately in solder.  Use a [metal soldering tip cleaner](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=solder+tip+cleaner+wire&t=opera&ia=web) to wipe it clean.  Place into holder.  Never dip the tip into flux.  When it is time to solder, always do these three steps: 1. Wipe the tip clean.  2. Make the solder joint, using extra flux at the joint if necessary.  3. Wipe the tip clean and place into holder.  You might be able to get away with making several joints sequentially before the tip needs cleaned again.

The combination of right-tool-for-the-job, better heat control, good tip quality, good solder, and good (rosin or synthetic) flux will make soldering less costly and much easier.

Comment: Lower temp solders aren't *always* weaker. If I recall correctly, Sn42/Bi58 solder is exceptionally strong, as long as you don't let any lead contaminate it.

Comment: For really tough desoldering jobs, I contaminate the joints with some special 205°C solder.  Getting that all off afterwards can be quite challenging.  Even touching the "cleaned" tip to an uncontaminated joint is enough to weaken it.  When strength / purity matters, it is easier to just keep a separate tip for those solders.

Comment: Cheap soldering irons always get way too hot.

Comment: "Wipe the tip clean and place into holder" I used to do this too, but at the IPC classes they un-teach this as a bad habit. When done soldering, you should rather bathe and cover the tip in generous amounts of solder, then turn off the heat and leave it with a lump of solder covering the tip. This prevents oxidation and leads to longer tip life.

Comment: True; I was assuming that "soldering" is typically plural, so little time between multiple joints.  But parking the iron "loaded" is a good idea.